# Convert Microsoft WGL4 charmap to wxString?

Tags: unicode, wxwidgets

I have some mutibyte data that are specified as "Microsoft WGL4 charmap, matching Unicode" which are returned from an external library.

These bultibyte data e.g. are some stuff like

```
}0fšÔ
```

(continues after that, the total length of this string is 16 bytes).

Now I want to convert them to a wxString showing the correct Unicode representation of them. But when I use these data as UTF8 and generate the wxString via wxString::FromUTF8(), the result is an empty string. When I use the data as UTF16 BE and convert via wxMBConvUTF16BE, the result is a hige string containing some crap only.

So...any idea how to correctly convert these "Microsoft WGL4 charmap" data to a wxString?

Thanks!

Comment: which encoding exactly the string is using?

Comment: Where are you getting "Microsoft WGL4 charmap"? WGL4 isn't a charmap; it's a set of Unicode characters recommended for support in fonts.